# Run JEST with AWS Credentials

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jestjs

I do have a question with regard to JEST. I tried to google it first of course but Im pretty sure I did not use the wrong key words. Here is my problem and I would love to be pointed into the correct direction.

Im using [awsume](https://awsu.me/) to load credentials into my VS Code terminal and then run my test with JEST. When using the JEST plugin I run into the understandable error that JEST does not have access to the credentials loaded in another terminal session.

For context: Im running a couple of commands against a test dynamoDB to set whether the DBController is working as expected.

Now my question: How to I enable JEST to either run awsume before it runs the test or how can I pass temporary credentials to it? If more info is needed please let me know :)

All the best
Christoph

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you're trying to run some tests on DynamoDB using Jest, but Jest doesn't have access to the AWS credentials that you loaded into your terminal using awsume. One way to fix this is by passing the temporary credentials to Jest using environment variables.

Think of environment variables as little pieces of information that programs can use to do their job. In this case, we want to set two environment variables in our terminal session: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. You can think of these like a username and password that allow you to access your AWS resources.

To set these environment variables, you can type the following commands into your terminal:

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id_here
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key_here

Remember to replace your_access_key_id_here and your_secret_access_key_here with the actual values that you got from awsume.

Once you've set these environment variables, Jest should be able to use them to authenticate with DynamoDB when running your tests.

If that doesn't work, another option would be to write a script that runs awsume to load the credentials and then runs Jest. You can call this script instead of calling Jest directly.

Comment: Hi Andy, welcome to the community! And thank you for your answer!

Your thinking is not 100% correct. Im already using JEST to run my tests from terminal. And this works. However, when Im using the JEST plugin for VS Code it does not because (my understanding) the plugin runs in its own terminal session which did not yet assume the aws IAM role.